# ajax fails on IE 10 when using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

i am using ajax call to a rest service.

it all works perfectly well on Chrome but when running it from IE 10 the ajax call fails.

I tried to print the error message but i didn't get something enlightening, is just says 'undefined'.

The ajax request is never sent to the server.
I saw posts talking about issues of IE with json but didn't find the right solution yet.

something more (don't know if it is relevant): if i try to go to the service url through IE 10 (putting the url in the browser) the JSON is not displayed.Instead it asks me if i want to open a file.

in addition: the request is done from an html file. (not under the same domain as the service).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
   var JSONObject= {
            "login":LogInUserName,
            "password": LogInPassword,
            };


    $.ajax({  
        url:'https .... ',  
        type:'post',
        data :  JSONObject,      
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('errors'))
                {
                    alert("errors found");
                    alert(data.errors);
                }
            else
                {
                    alert("data sent!");

                }


            }  ,
        error: function (request, status, error)  {
            alert ("error before sending");
            alert(request.responseText);
            location.reload();

        }


    });
```

Comment: try removing extra comma here: `"password": LogInPassword,` Shouldn't be any more an issue on IE10 but who knows?!

Comment: Have you tried using IE10's debugger? Press F12 to open, click the Scripts tab, and click Start Debugging - you can set breakpoints and see what variables are at specific times. EDIT: Also, Wolff is right - while other browsers can often handle those extra commas okay, that has messed up IE many times for me.

Comment: You could try to add, `cache: false` to the ajax call, don't know if it's true of IE10 but IE8 had a habit of trying to cache ajax calls which would result in then essentially returning no data

Comment: What does the "error" argument in your error callback indicate?

Comment: About the debugger - everthing works fine until and ajax call and to step into it and start debugging is... harsh.  cache: false didn't solve it...

Comment: Are you going cross-site with the AJAX request? i.e. is your website on the same domain as the service (which I note is HTTPS)?

Comment: Yes. my website (an html file) is not on the same domain as the  service

Comment: Have you tried with $.getJSON? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: In that case it does sounds like you are cross-domain posting, to a secure site, in which case *no browser should allow it* (by default). This is to protect the websites from unauthorised use. You will need to start reading up on (a lot) of posts regarding cross-domain solutions, but often the best solution is to access that service from your web-server and make it available to your client from the same domain.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing you need to do is learn to properly debug and become best friends with `F12`, the Console tab, and the Network tab:

**This tutorial shows Google Chrome but the SAME EXACT idea applies to IE or FireFox**

### 1 - use console.log() instead of alert()

```
var JSONObject = {
    "login": LogInUserName,
    "password": LogInPassword // get rid of the comma, stop being lazy
};


$.ajax({
    url: 'https .... ',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSONObject,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {

        // hit F12 and check the console
        console.log(data); // F off alert()!

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {

        console.log(request); // F off alert()!
        console.log(status); // F off alert()!
        console.log(error); // F off alert()!

        // don't reload, we have an issue
        // location.reload();

    }


});
```

### 2 - Get cozy with F12

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

- Press F12
- Go to Network Tab
- Type something on the website and hit **Go**
- Click on that beast and check for errors in the Response or Preview tabs

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer. More a general set of useful things to try. Better off as comment(s).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie great, how do I insert that image with mini-markdown?

Comment: You can't insert images, although you could explain it in text, but a tutorial like that belongs on a blog (which you *can* link to). Just saying, this is not an answer but a comment (a very big comment) :)

Comment: Lol I knew that, I don't have a blog but maybe I can turn this into a StackOverflow WIKI or something.